# How to convert String type of dataset to float ? (CNN)

Tags: python, conv-neural-network

I have been getting this error :
UnimplementedError:  Cast string to float is not supported
[[node categorical_crossentropy/Cast (defined at :2) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_1154]

I found out that my dataset dtype should be same.

code :

```
X_train, X_test , y_train , y_test  = train_test_split(data, labels ,test_size = 0.3, random_state  = 1 )
print(X_train.shape , y_train.shape , X_test.shape , y_test.shape)
print(X_train.dtype)
print(y_train.dtype)
print(X_test.dtype)
print(y_test.dtype)
```

o/p  :

```
(432, 50, 50, 3) (432,) (186, 50, 50, 3) (186,)
float64
<U7
float64
<U7
```

How do I get X_train and X_test to float ?
Also, why did the dtype change to string when I split the data into train and test ?

[image: y_test, y_train and labels]

[image: Here]

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me for a different application and may work for you:

```py
# X_train is a list of lists containing the data
x_tr = np.array(X_train)
x_tr = x_tr.astype(np.float64)
```

Comment: Tried it and got this error instead : 
UnimplementedError:  Cast string to float is not supported
  [[node categorical_crossentropy/Cast (defined at <ipython-input-13-59f0001da0f5>:2) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_2305]